# Add array of HH:MM:SS values in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array of time values as.

```
var time = [
    "03:05:11",
    "00:00:12",
    "03:03:14"
]
```

How do I add all the array values such that I get the output as `"06:08:37"` (sum of `"03:05:11" + "00:00:12" + "03:03:14"` ).

If there are `N` no of array values, how do we do it without looping in node.js ?

Comment: What do you mean "without looping in nodejs", you have an array and you want to extract a sum. How else could this be done without looping?

Comment: If my array.length=1000, it repeats for 1000 times, so i am looking for more effective method

Comment: you cant repeat less than N times. it's obvious that if you need to calculate the sum, you need to pass through the whole array. any solution you will find will not be less than N passes.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)

First we'll need to parse time spans into something usable for calculations using moment.duration constructor and then we use an array reduce to sum up these values:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var sum = [
  "03:05:11",
  "00:00:12",
  "03:03:14"
].map(t => moment.duration(t))
.reduce((sum, current) => sum.add(current), moment.duration());
```

For formatting sum to a "hh:mm:ss" format the moment-duration-format plugin could be used (https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format):

```
console.log(sum.format("hh:mm:ss"));
```

This answer requires looping as all answers will since data is stored in an array.

*Hand babelified ES5 version*

```
var sum = [
  "03:05:11",
  "00:00:12",
  "03:03:14"
].map(function(t) { return moment.duration(t); })
.reduce(function(sum, current) { return sum.add(current); }, moment.duration());
```

Comment: /test.js:6
].map(t => moment.duration(t))
        ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3 i am getting this error when i tried.thank you

Comment: I'm using es6 syntax here so node 4.x or higher is required to run the code.

Comment: i am using node 0.12.2 version.please suggest me the method which supports my version